# how about run Subsonic version 2 and 3 together?

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

Today I compile subsonic version **with different namespace (as subsonic3)** and place it **together with subsonic version 2**.

Also create all files (for both versions, in different dlls) for my database with success, and make simple tests, and seams that everything works perfect.

This is my simple test code, and you can see 3 and 2 run together.

```
var PageTitlesOn3 = from p in ATH_Store_Product.All()
                      where p.ProductID == 1
                        select p;

foreach (ATH_Store_Product Ena in PageTitlesOn3)
{
    txtOnMe.Text += string.Format("<br />{0} ) {1}", 
            Ena.ProductID, Ena.ProductName);
}

AthStoreProductCollection AllMyTitlesAgainOn2 = new AthStoreProductCollection()
    .Where(AthStoreProduct.Columns.ProductID, 1)
    .Load();

foreach (AthStoreProduct Ena in AllMyTitlesAgainOn2)
{
    txtOnMe.Text += string.Format("<br />{0} ) {1}", 
            Ena.ProductID, Ena.ProductName);
}
```

I did that, because I like to move to subsonic 3, but I need to do that one piece at the time, some part code, then some other part etc.

My project is a little bit huge, and run online, and I do not won't to stop it run.
This way, placing subsonic 2 and 3, working together, I can start migrating my code in time.

**Now my question is if I am doing any big error,** and if they going to crash after run together all their time, if I eat a lot of resources, etc.

I have looked the source code of subsonic, but I am not that familiar (yet) with what really do, what and how is open the database etc…

Now, **my second question is, why not subsonic ver3, permanently renamed to subsonic3**, and other users do the same think that I did.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong here, after all, it is as if you have two DAL's, one of which it tends to disappear in favor of the other.